# Even with space my AWS EC2 instance show message "No space left on device"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My AWS EC2 Instance have the properties below:

[image]

As We can see, there is 6,4GB free space, but even with this space when accessing my app in this intance the message "No space left on device" is showing.

Why does it happen?

Comment: If you have disk space, but your app says it doesn't... maybe take a look at the app and see what it does to determine how much space it has?

Comment: @Evert My application is not calculating disk space, just trying to perform a task and returning this message

Comment: Can you elaborate what this task is?

Comment: @Evert, to save a PDF file with 68KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is not with EC2, but with Linux in general.

Check your `inodes`, you can have free disk space but saturated your `inodes`

Example:

```
$ df -i .
Filesystem                   Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 3219456 330596 2888860   11% /
```

Comment: Hi @Azize I ran the command and returned 100% usage, no free space. What should I do to free up space?

Comment: Well, in this case you need to remove some files or increase your filesystem or reduce the block size (not know if it is even possible). I can't give you a complete answer in this comment, I guess google can help you more, but in general filesystem is formed of blocks. The block (also know as inode) has a size, imagine your block size is 16kb, if you create a file that is only 1kb, you will have 15kb of free space, bit it will consume one entire inode. This is exaclty your problem, probably you have a lot of small files.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you more. https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-disk-inodes

Answer (score 0):

A reason why 'No space left on device' might appear, even if `df` suggests that there's space available, is if:

1. A file was opened by a program
2. Subsequently, the file got deleted
3. The program is still running and it still has an open file handle

Linux only really deletes files when all references to the file have disappeared. This includes references such as files, but also open file handles.

If you recently deleted a particularly large file, there is probably a program on your system that still has that file open. If you have a good idea what program that is, the simplest might be to just restart that program.